# configuration of db/seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I pushed my to do list application to github.

Nor users, nor admins are created. The db is not uploaded to github (and should not).
so I should add all initial setup to db/seeds.rb to ensure that all db expectations are in place.

In addition, the Roles are not created in the seeds file, so the application fails to register users.

I tried to add all initial setup to `db/seeds.rb`:

```
Role.create({name: "Admin"})
Role.create({name: "Woeker"})

user1 = User.create!(
    email: "admin2@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
    encrypted_password: "$2a$10$7aK4tZTsCDB64qQI/kl.d.nZGwjEJPh7YlUNE8/Ty.0JhAMS.ALX6"
    role_ids = [1]
)

user2 = User.create!(
    email: "worker2@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
    encrypted_password: "$2a$10$7aK4tZTsCDB64qQI/kl.d.nZGwjEJPh7YlUNE8/Ty.0JhAMS.ALX6"
    role_ids = [2]
)
```

(the encrypted_password was taken from the rails console: u = user.last..)

Unfortunately, I'm not sure If I added all what I have to, and if I did it exactly.

in the page of `localhost:3000/users/sign_up`, I have to enter: Email, Password and Password confirmation.

These are the migrations:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
end



class Roles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles
  end
end



class UserRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE: THIS IS THE SOLUTION?**

```
Role.create({name: "Admin"})
Role.create({name: "Woeker"})

user1 = User.create!(
    email: "admin2@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
    role_ids = [1]
)

user2 = User.create!(
    email: "worker2@gmail.com",
    password: "12345678",
    password_confirmation: "12345678"
    role_ids = [2]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something like that. Remove the password confirmation. Do exactly as if you were in the sign in form.

Comment: I am editing my topic with the solution. tell me if it is correct. another thing, I have to define the role. in the rails console I define it by: u = user.last   u.role_ids = [2]   u.save. so pay attention please if I did it exactly. thank you very much! you don't have any idea how much you help me!

Comment: I am fairly new to Rails too. I didn't even know that ` u.role_ids = [2]` was possible. Sorry! What I mean is: you will have to test that one.